Kotlin, how to create a generic factory that creates subtypes?
I am struggling to find a way to reduce the factory boilerplate in my code.
I have a base view model class, that all view models extend from. This view model uses generics to determine the type of its arguments. I also have an abstract factory, that holds the logic of how the object must be created:
abstract class BaseViewModel<T : BaseViewModel.In>(val arguments: T) : ViewModel(){
  
  interface In

  abstract class Factory<X : BaseViewModel<*>> : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    abstract fun get(): X

    override fun <U : ViewModel> create(
        modelClass: KClass<U>,
        extras: CreationExtras
    ): U {
       return get() as U
     }
  }

}

The idea is that every viewmodel subclass should have a factory inside that extends from this base factory and overrides the get method, implementing the logic to create the instances
I have this ExampleVM, to try it out:
class ExampleVM(arguments: In) : BaseViewModel<ExampleVM.In>(arguments = arguments) {

    @Serializable
    data class In(val number: Int) : BaseViewModel.In

      class Factory(private val args: In) : BaseViewModel.Factory<ExampleVM>() {
          override fun get(): ExampleVM {
              return ExampleVM(args)
          }
      }

 }

There are a couple of things that I wish to improve:
1- Most of the times, the arguments: T is the only type I pass to the constructor. Therefore would be nice to have a generic/base factory that spits out the correct type, based on the type used to create the factory.
2- Since there's no such thing as a extending/overriding a static / companion object, I'm struggling to achieve this: I want to have a static factory() method in the BaseViewModel companion object, that spits out a factory, to be accessed as BaseViewModel.factory(), but then assume X extends from BaseViewModel, I would like that X.factory() would try to use the implementation found inside the companion object of class X. Is something like that possible?
The whole idea is that I want to reduce the boilerplate code and make a generic function that takes care of calling the factory for all the view models that extend from BaseViewModel
This is my view function:
composable<ExampleVM.In> { backStackEntry ->
            val arguments = backStackEntry.toRoute<ExampleVM.In>()
            val vm: ExampleVM = viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity, factory = ExampleVM.Factory(args = arguments), key = arguments.toString())
            ExampleVMView(viewModel = vm)

}
And it is like that for every single view, always getting the argument from the route, and then creating the view model using the factory from the type of the view model. I would love to be able to make a generic function for this.
Any tips?

Honestly, I don't fully understand your idea. Let's start with the basics, with your current solution. Why/how the create function could be possibly type-safe? X and U are unrelated, they could be two entirely different things. What's the meaning of In interface? I believe it is not used.

@broot U exists just because this function overrides the method from the factory I am extending demands it. Ideally I would get rid of it and make that function return X instead, getting rid of one unnecessary generics.
T extends from In and is the type of the arguments held by BaseViewModel. It is currently empty, but I could add some stuff to it later on.
